# Is it possible to find the fields in class under package using java reflection

Tags: java, reflection

```
public class InpackageTest {
                private static Class[] getClasses(String packageName)
                        throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
                    File classpathLocation =null; 
                    System.out.println("package name - > "+packageName);
                    ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
                    assert classLoader != null;
                    String path = packageName.replace('.', '/');
                    System.out.println("path --- name - > "+path);
                    Enumeration resources = classLoader.getResources(path);
                    List<File> dirs = new ArrayList<File>();
                    while (resources.hasMoreElements()) {
                        URL resource = (URL) resources.nextElement();
                        classpathLocation = new File(resource.getFile());
                        System.err.println("resource.getFile()- > "+resource.getFile());
                        dirs.add(new File(resource.getFile()));
                    }
                    ArrayList classes = new ArrayList();
                    System.out.println("dirs- > "+dirs.size());
                    for (File directory : dirs) {
                        classes.addAll(findClasses(classpathLocation, packageName));
                    }
                    return (Class[]) classes.toArray(new Class[classes.size()]);
                }

                 private static List findClasses(File directory, String packageName) throws ClassNotFoundException {
                        List classes = new ArrayList();
                        System.out.println("directory > "+directory.getName()+" -- > pacakge- > "+packageName);
                        if (directory.exists()) {
                            System.out.println("Dir exist - > "+directory.exists());
                            return classes;
                        }

                        System.out.println("directory- > "+directory.getAbsolutePath());
                        File[] files = directory.listFiles();

                        for (File file : files) {
                            System.out.println("file name - > "+file.getName());
                            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                                assert !file.getName().contains(".");
                                classes.addAll(findClasses(file, packageName + "." + file.getName()));
                            } else if (file.getName().endsWith(".class")) {
                                classes.add(Class.forName(packageName + '.' + file.getName().substring(0, file.getName().length() - 6)));
                            }
                        }
                        return classes;
                    }


                public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
                    List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
                    List<String> listOfClasses_Name = new ArrayList<String>();
                      List<Field> Fields = new ArrayList<>();

                      try {
            Class [] c =InpackageTest.getClasses("com.compensation.content");
                        System.out.println(c.getClass().getName().toString());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
```

Here i have try to get the field under the package in same project.package name given,i cant get the list of files under the folder.
Question becomes : how can i get the java files under some specific location in my system using java reflection(Moto: need to get all the fields under the class which is reside under some folder.)

Comment: Do you want files or classes? If files why don't you use File class options (testing if it is a directory and then list files in it )?

Comment: @Nemesis, I need classes in folder and field in each class.

Comment: You need to use ASM to parse the class files. [Reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) does what you want, but if you want to see how to implement it yourself, maybe see [Brian Clapper's impl](https://github.com/bmc/javautil/blob/master/src/main/java/org/clapper/util/classutil/ClassFinder.java).